# Error a ejecutar proyecto en React-Native

Tags: react-native, instalacion

he realizado la intalacion de React-Native pero al momento de ejecutar el comando react-native run-android  no me ejecuta y me sale el siguiente error, por favor su apoyo para encontra la solucion

---

C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio>react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'limpio'.

  > Text must not be null or empty
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'limpio'.

  > Text must not be null or empty
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)
at then.result (C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

---

C:\Users\Dezbrid\Documents\ETDM7\ANDROID HIBRIDO\React\REACTNATIVE\limpio>react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Windows 10
    CPU: (8) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
    Memory: 2.77 GB / 6.90 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.4.0.0 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156

Answer (score 1):

Busca en tus componentes si tienes un elemento  vacio, esto no es permitido, el elemento podria verse asi `<Text></Text>` o asi `<Text/>`

Answer (score 0):

Sin poder ver los archivos de configuración de tu proyecto ni el código que utilizas es complicado ayudarte.

El error 'Text must not be null or empty' no esta asociado a ningún elemento Text como te comentaba Luis Suarez, de hecho pueden estar vacíos sin problema.

Siguiendo la traza del error todo apunta a que tu entorno de desarrollo no está correctamente configurado, solo puedo aconsejarte que sigas minuciosamente las instrucciones del enlace que te proporciona el error https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment hasta que puedas iniciar tu 'Hello World App'.

Como recomendación adicional, usa Expo en tu proyecto. Te facilitará algunas cosas.